# Wi-Fi shows a connection, but no page will load

Tags: wireless

I'm new to Linux, well being re-introduced to it and I am attempting to dual-boot it on my old laptop. It's running Vista and the Wi-Fi works just fine on Vista.

At any rate, Ubuntu runs just fine at start-up the programs I have work just fine. The computer will detect the wireless, it will connect but it does not work. No page will load. I've tried several things I've seen around the internet, and reverted said settings because they were all not working.

- The laptop in question is a Asus Altec Lansing
- I'm running Ubuntu 16.04
- The Wi-Fi card is an `Atheros AR928X`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I tried running the wireless script via usb but it does not display any information only one line that says wireless info start.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` and then reboot

Comment: The only issue is I don't have a connection when I hop back and forth. I'm going to give this a go, and I'll let you know.

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit your question to include results.  There are mixed results with that wifi chip in 16.04 but I have one that works

Comment: I tried you first suggestion Jeremy and it said there's no such file or directory.

Comment: I don't have a way to connect via an Ethernet cord, is there a script I could use that doesn't require internet?

Comment: see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385&viewfull=1#post12350385) to see how to run the script without internet.  Try the command again, it has to be exact the symbol between " and  sudo | is a pipe symbol.  I get it by pressing shift and the  \ key.  Enter the command as one line

Comment: I tried the script again, and it's still a no-go. I'm assuming I'd missed a letter, while it did not give the error, it still didn't solve the problem. The script, I made the file executable, ran it and the only thing it shows in the file afterwards is " wireless info START" and the rest is blank.

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/T65FyDpF for a long command to run, it is used by Launchpads Answer site, well part of it.  You will have to copy it to Ubuntu terminal and then copy the info.txt file back to computer with internet.  I would suggest using pastebin.com to paste the contents of info.txt  I had to remove some commands as they required internet access

Comment: Here's what that command generated http://pastebin.com/rRYzJgA0

Comment: Did the terminal go back to a prompt at that point?  My terminal paused at the point where your info stops but kept running.  Can you `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I just got to work, I'll give that a try when I get home,  I'll also run your script again to make sure it's finished.

Comment: You were right, Jeremy. The script wasn't completed yet, here's the result of the completed script and ping. http://pastebin.com/gAVWQ3FP

Comment: See if `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` helps at all and check the wifi router for any kind of blocks